# Compilation error with Mojave: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type

Tags: command-line, xcode, gcc

After updating to Mojave 10.14.4 and Xcode 10.2, I fail to compile GCC 8.3.0. The error message is

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/sysctl.h:83,
                 from ../../gcc-8.3.0/gcc/config/darwin-driver.c:30:
/usr/include/sys/ucred.h:94:2: error: ‘_Atomic’ does not name a type
  _Atomic u_long          cr_ref;  /* reference count */
  ^~~~~~~
```

I have not found any clue how this can be fixed. The header in question is

```
struct ucred {
    LIST_ENTRY(ucred)       cr_link; /* never modify this without KAUTH_CRED_HASH_LOCK */
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L && !defined(__STDC_NO_ATOMICS__)
    _Atomic u_long          cr_ref;  /* reference count */
#elif defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L
    _Atomic u_long          cr_ref;  /* reference count */   // <--- this line
#else
    volatile u_long         cr_ref;  /* reference count */
#endif
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I was in the process of writing an answer for you when this was put on hold: "You need to use a C11 compatible compiler in order to have support for the _Atomic keyword. 

Ensure that you are compiling with a recent, modern compiler, and that __STDC_NO_ATOMICS__ is not defined.
"

Comment: @nohillside This is not a software development question. It is a user trying to install GCC 8.3.0 by compiling the software - not a user trying to develop new software.

Comment: How are you compiling gcc. Easiest way is to use macports or homebrew. If you do not want to do that then at least see how they got the compile to work.

Comment: @jksoegaard Thanks, please post your answer

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am not able to compile a program using the GNU G++ 7 from MacPorts, when including the tbb/parallel_sort.h. It prints the exact same error message, but my trace goies to Xcode /usr/include/sys/sysctl.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem myself. The error is actually reported by g++, a C++ compiler. On MacOS 10.14.4, the header file `<sys/ucred.h>` uses the `_Atomic` keyword for C++, although it is only defined in the C standard. (I assume that Apple's compiler `clang++` defines this keyword as extension to the C++ standard.)

The proper fix is to tell gcc to "fixinclude" the header file `<sys/ucred.h>`. [This patch](https://gist.github.com/eschnett/f912c6b791e29c83477575017271db16) does this. This is a patch that needs to be applied to the source code of GCC 8.3.0 before building it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixes the build! If the same trick is also done in the sanitizer's code, I could also build GCC from trunk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a C11 compatible compiler in order to have support for the _Atomic keyword.

Ensure that you are compiling with a recent, modern compiler, and that **STDC_NO_ATOMICS** is not defined.

It might be easier for you to use HomeBrew in order to compile it without having to configure anything yourself. After installing HomeBrew, you can install gcc with:

```
brew install gcc
```

Comment: I am using Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3) which should be C11 compatible. It does not define `STDC_NO_ATOMICS`.

Comment: I do want to compile GCC myself, because the latest versions are not always available on Homebrew. Furthermore, this used to work, and I would like to fix this :)

Comment: I'm encountering this same issue as OP and homebrew fails with the same error.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I found a solution [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/).

> macOS Mojave changed the location of the system headers, this broke the GCC 8 build process. In order to build GCC install the required header files in the old location:

The solution is to install the package found in the following directory.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
```

Comment: I did that, yet it does not fix the described issue. The answer of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355103/325679 fixes the issue.